# TcpClient NetworkStream gets stuck until TcpClient closed

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I want to send messages between the server and the client through TcpClient. Here's my code. The client sends "HELLO" to the server, the server prints the message after receiving it, and sends "HI" to the client, the client prints the message after receiving it.

Note the code at (1) in the Client code, the program will be stuck here. If I remove this code, the program can run normally, but of course, the client cannot receive the response from the server. What's the problem and how to solve it? Thx.

**Server**

```
void Main()
{
    var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
    listener.Start();

    var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    var rs = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
    var msg = rs.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"RECEIVED: {msg}");

    var ws = client.GetStream();
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HI");
    ws.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    client.Close();
}
```

**Client**

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);

    var ws = client.GetStream();
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HELLO");
    ws.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    var msg = "nothing";
    msg = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()).ReadLine(); //(1)
    Console.WriteLine($"RECEIVED: {msg}");

    client.Close();
}
```

Comment: One possible problem is that your programs don't actually send *lines* as the data being sent is missing the newlines.

Comment: You're right, that's exactly why. Thank you.